# React hooks, provide context but don't rerender children on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal is to be able to have a timer that children can access. The problem is that only a few components need the seconds value but many need to be able to manipulate the timer (pausing it, changing the value, resetting it, etc). My solution was to wrap all of the children in it but the child which accesses it is still rendered every time that second updates - even though I'm not unpacking the seconds in the context.

Here's the wrapper:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Timer, {ITimerSettings} from '../../utilities/Timer';

export const TimerContext = React.createContext({
   seconds: null,
   setTimer: null,
   timer: null
});
export const TimerProvider = TimerContext.Provider;
export const TimerConsumer = TimerContext.Consumer;

interface ITimerWrapperProps {
   isPaused: boolean;
   isReady: boolean;
   children: any;
}

const TimerWrapper: React.FC<ITimerWrapperProps> = ({isReady, isPaused, children}) => {

   const timer = React.useRef<Timer>(new Timer());
   const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState<number>(null);

   React.useEffect(() => {
      if (isReady && timer.current && timer.current.duration) {
         isPaused ? timer.current.stop() : timer.current.start();
      }
   }, [isReady, isPaused]);

   const setTimer = React.useCallback((settings: Partial<ITimerSettings>): void => {
      if (timer.current) {
         timer.current.reset({
            callback: i => setSeconds(i),
            ...settings
         });
      }
   }, []);

   return (
      <TimerProvider value={{seconds, timer, setTimer}}>
         {children}
      </TimerProvider>
   );
};

export default React.memo(TimerWrapper);
```

Here's how the child is accessing it:

```
   const {timer, setTimer} = React.useContext(TimerContext);
```

My question is, why is the child re-rendering every time that seconds updates and how can I prevent it? Do I need to split up the contexts so there's one for the seconds and one for the timer?

Comment: Try to pass timer ref directly, but not the `timer.current`, 'cause `timer.current` has a new value every single timer update (if I understand properly) and try to store seconds in a ref. You probably don't want to update any props on every timer tick

Comment: good idea - I tried passing only the ref and accessing it with timer.current but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context value is a new object every render, so every time the second updates

```
<TimerProvider value={ {seconds, timer, setTimer} }>
```

You want the components that use the seconds to update with the `seconds` value and components that only use the controls to never rerender.

I think I would split this into a `TimerValueContext` and a `TimerControlsContext`. Where the controls would always have the same instance for its value. Then the consumers can pick one or both.

Something like this: (probably not working code)

```
const TimerControlsContext = React.createContext({
   setTimer: null,
   timer: null
});

const TimerValueContext = React.createContext(0);

export const useTimerValue = () => {
    const context = useContext(TimerValueContext);
    if (context) return context;
    throw new Error('Outside of provider!');
};

export const useTimerControls = () => {
    const context = useContext(TimerControlsContext);
    if (context) return context;
    throw new Error('Outside of provider!');
};

interface ITimerWrapperProps {
   isPaused: boolean;
   isReady: boolean;
   children: any;
}

const TimerWrapper: React.FC<ITimerWrapperProps> = ({isReady, isPaused, children}) => {

   const timer = React.useRef<Timer>(new Timer());
   const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState<number>(null);

   React.useEffect(() => {
      if (isReady && timer.current && timer.current.duration) {
         isPaused ? timer.current.stop() : timer.current.start();
      }
   }, [isReady, isPaused]);

   const setTimer = React.useCallback((settings: Partial<ITimerSettings>): void => {
      if (timer.current) {
         timer.current.reset({
            callback: i => setSeconds(i),
            ...settings
         });
      }
   }, []);


   const [controlsInstance, _] = React.useState({timer, setTimer});

   return (
      <TimerControlsContext.Provider value={controlsInstance}>
            <TimerValueContext.Provider value={seconds}>
                 {children}
           <TimerValueContext.Provider>
      </TimerControlsContext>
   );
};

export default React.memo(TimerWrapper);
```

Comment: This seemed to work - breaking the the getter and setter into two separate contexts! The only thing that I'm confused on is, why do the controls need to be put into their own state? I thought that by using a ref for the timer and useCallback for the setTimer function that it wouldn't be necessary?

Comment: I think `<TimerProvider value={ {seconds, timer, setTimer} }>` is the crucial bit. The value there is a new object every time and even if a consumer only destructures out the unchanged `timer` instance, the anonymous object that contains it has changed when the `seconds` value caused it to update.

Comment: The reason that I ask about the state is I tried it first with the separate providers but  didn't use the controls instance part (I just passed in the timer and setTimer directly) and it didn't work. It worked when I added the useState though.